# How to make a condition?

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements

I have request

```
SELECT IF(f.date_term=3,t.quarter*f.date_term ,''),
       IF(f.date_term=6,t.halfyear*f.date_term,''),
       IF(f.date_term=12,t.year*f.date_term,'')
```

but this is not work.

how to make a condition? I need one value IF ( date_term == 3 ) {select quarter} ELSE IF ( date_term == 6) {halfyear} ....

Comment: Just as a comment, consider the design of your software because I think it's good practise to keep your logic separate from your queries

Comment: There are languages (e.g. 4GL) where almost all logic is in the queries. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [CASE expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html):

```
SELECT CASE f.date_term
         WHEN 3 THEN t.quarter
         WHEN 6 THEN t.halfyear
         WHEN 12 THEN t.year
       END AS term_interval,
       ...
```

There's nothing to stop you from doing the calculation at the same time:

```
SELECT CASE f.date_term
         WHEN 3 THEN t.quarter * f.date_term
         WHEN 6 THEN t.halfyear * f.date_term
         WHEN 12 THEN t.year * f.date_term
       END AS term_calc,
       ...
```